# How to turn values of select options into simple array with ES6 syntax?

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of select options like these:

```
const options = document.querySelectorAll('select option');
```

How can I turn only the **values** of these select options into a simple array?

I tried doing this...

```
const array = Array.from(options);
```

... and I am getting something that pretends (?) to be an array but is actually a `NodeList` (please correct me if I am confusing something here) and contains far too much information.

What I actually need is a simple array of option values like `[3, 5, 2]`.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<select>
   <option value="3">Alpha</option>
   <option value="5">Beta</option>
   <option value="2">Gamma</option>
</select>
```

I would like to use the latest ES6 syntax.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `options` is a `NodeList`, but `array` should be a real array.

Comment: It's an array of `HTMLOptionElement` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the value as well with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

```js
const
    options = document.querySelectorAll('select option'),
    array = Array.from(options, ({ value }) => value);

console.log(array);
```

```html
<select>
   <option value="3">Alpha</option>
   <option value="5">Beta</option>
   <option value="2">Gamma</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I didn't know about the second argument to `Array.from()`. That's clever.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.from` doesn't magically extract a property out of every object you pass to it. To get the values, `map` over the array of HTMLElements that you get

```
const values = Array.from(options).map(e => e.value);
```